# How to choose one list random from multiple lists python

Tags: python

I have a function that returns multiple lists, I need to choose one list from it to deal with

```
   def levy_flight() :

    for i in range(cf.Config.get_population_size()): # cf.Config.get_population_size = 4
        chromo = (createindivisual.init_solution())
        Obj = Objective(i, chromo)

        return Obj.individual, Obj.chromosome
```

I get this output

```
0
[2 3 5 6 0 3 2 0 1 1]

1
[6 9 8 8 4 1 0 0 2 2]

2
[4 3 3 1 1 1 0 9 8 4]

3
[0 5 3 2 2 1 8 9 0 9]
```

I need to choose a random list from the above lists please help me

Comment: Please can you share some code and some tries ? Please [edit] your post and add it

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Module `random` can work with different objects.

Comment: How are the multipe list stored? Could you please give an example. And please do not add code as a picture. Use the code block instead.

Comment: Your method actually returns nothing, it just prints somt stuff. Also don't post picture f your code, rather your code as text

Comment: Do you want to apply the code for only one `i` in the whole range in fact ?

Comment: No, I wanted to select one list randomly from the output lists

Answer (score 1):

Hi look at the `random` module, specially at the `random.choice` function. It will return an random element from a list.

Comment: I do not need to return an element, but return to the list from multiple lists

Comment: @Black77 Please if you have time to comment, you have time to update your post and show your efforts. Please add some code and clarify, because that answer seems to be the good one